# Getting value of a button and use it in another page in php

Tags: php, database

I have designed a table in index.php page that gets data from database, with these columns:

Full name, email, address (of customers) and the last column of each row has a edit button with `<a ></a> tag`, that its href links to another page :

`href = "edit.php?id= ' " .$row['customer'] .    " ' "`

Now, edit.php page includes a form that admin can make changes in customers data.
To do this I need to get the id of each customer while clicking on the "edit" button and direct to edit.php page, to show their information in the form as a default values (that admin can change them) .
How would I do this?

I hope I make myself understood.

Comment: We can't understand your doubt. Explain it clearly

Comment: Can you post minimal code which  you have implemented for this ?

Answer (score 0):

In the edit button pass the `id` as a parameter in the url and then retrive the id from the url in edit.php and fetch the user from the table again based on the id and then make changes in the data and post the user data with new data back to the mysql table
As you are using anchor tag Pass the id like this

There should be a column id on the table and just to make it easy make this column auto Inreamentable
Hope it works

Comment: I think I got you, I'll try it then I'll tell you if it worked... thanks

Answer (score 0):

@faro621, You can get the id in `edit.php` page and run the query for select the customer data by that id and show the information.Like this-

`$q = 'Select * from table_name where id ="'.$_REQUEST['id'].'" ';` 
Execute this query now you will get the data on the same page.

*Hope it will help you.*

Comment: SorryI didn't get you exactly, I am an amateur and maybe that's why I can't make myself understood... see I have written value of input tag in page edit.php this way:  $q = 'SELECT `first_name` FROM table_name WHERE id = 1';  and this works well , but I want to know what should I write instead of id=1 to make it dynamic that by clicking on edit buttons, each of them take its row's id to edit.php page.